# Writing own function using dplyr and group_by - how to continue with changed column names

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I would like to make tables for publication that give the number of observations, grouped by two variables. The code for this works fine. However, I have run into problems when trying to turn this into a function.

I am using dplyr_0.7.2

Example using mtcars:

## Code for table outside of function: this works

```
library(tidyverse) 

tab1 <- mtcars %>% count(cyl) %>% rename(Total = n) 

tab2 <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>% count %>% 
  spread(gear, n)

tab <- full_join(tab1, tab2, by = "cyl")
tab


# This is the output (which is what I want)

A tibble: 3 x 5
cyl Total   `3`   `4`   `5`
<dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     4    11     1     8     2
2     6     7     2     4     1
3     8    14    12    NA     2
```

## Trying to put this into a function

Function for tab1: this works

```
count_by_two_groups_A <- function(df, var1){
  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  tab1 <- df %>% count(!!var1) %>% rename(Total = n)
  tab1
} 

count_by_two_groups_A(mtcars, cyl) 

A tibble: 3 x 2
cyl Total
<dbl> <int>
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14
```

Function for first part of tab2: it works up to this point, but...

```
count_by_two_groups_B <- function(df, var1, var2){

  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  var2 <- enquo(var2)

  tab2 <- df %>% group_by((!!var1), (!!var2)) %>% count
  tab2
} 

count_by_two_groups_B(mtcars, cyl, gear)

A tibble: 8 x 3
Groups:   (cyl), (gear) [8]
 `(cyl)` `(gear)`     n
 <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
 1       4        3     1
 2       4        4     8
 3       4        5     2
 4       6        3     2
 5       6        4     4
 6       6        5     1
 7       8        3    12
 8       8        5     2
```

The column names have changed to (cyl) and (gear). I can't seem to figure out how to carry on with spread() and full_join() (or anything else using the new column names) now that the column names have changed. I.e. I can't figure out how to specify the new column names in the tidyeval way, to be able to carry on. I have tried various things, without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way of setting names in a tidyeval context is to use the definition operator `:=`. It would look like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(
    !! nm1 := !! var1,
    !! nm2 := !! var2
  ) %>%
  count()
```

For this you need to extract `nm1` from `var1`. Unfortunately I don't have an easy way of stripping down the enclosing parentheses yet. I think it'd make sense to do it in the forthcoming function `ensym()` (it captures symbols instead of quosures and issue an error if you supply a call). I have submitted a ticket here: https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/issues/223

Fortunately we have two easy solutions here. First note that you don't need the enclosing parentheses. They are only needed when other operators are involved in the captured expression. E.g. in these situations:

```
(!! var) / avg
(!! var) < value
```

In this case if you omitted parentheses, `!!` would try to unquote the whole expressions instead of just the one symbol. On the other hand in your function there is no operator so you can safely unquote without enclosing:

```
count_by_two_groups_B <- function(df, var1, var2) {
  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  var2 <- enquo(var2)

  df %>%
    group_by(!! var1, !! var2) %>%
    count()
}
```

Finally, you could make your function more general by allowing a variable number of arguments. This is even easier to implement because dots are *forwarded* so there is no need to capture and unquote. Just pass them down to `group_by()`:

```
count_by <- function(df, ...) {
  df %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    count()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can make it work with NSE (non-standard evaluation). Could not do it with tidyverse as I did not have that installed and did not bother installing.

Here is a working code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

count_by_two_groups_B <- function(df, var1, var2){

 # var1 <- enquo(var1)
 # var2 <- enquo(var2)

  tab2 <- df %>% group_by_(var1, var2) %>% summarise(n = n() )  %>%spread(gear, n)

  tab2
} 

count_by_two_groups_B(mtcars, 'cyl', 'gear')
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl   `3`   `4`   `5`
* <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1     4     1     8     2
2     6     2     4     1
3     8    12    NA     2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those situations where reaching for dplyr or tidyverse seems excessive. There are base functions to do this ... `table` and to make the results in long form, `as.dataframe`:

```
as.data.frame( with(mtcars, table(cyl,gear)) , responseName="Total")
#--------
  cyl gear Total
1   4    3     1
2   6    3     2
3   8    3    12
4   4    4     8
5   6    4     4
6   8    4     0
7   4    5     2
8   6    5     1
9   8    5     2
```

This would be one dplyr approach:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl,gear) %>% summarise(Total=n())
#----
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [?]
    cyl  gear Total
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     4     3     1
2     4     4     8
3     4     5     2
4     6     3     2
5     6     4     4
6     6     5     1
7     8     3    12
8     8     5     2
```

And if the question was how to get this as a table object (thinking that might have been your goal with `spread` then just:

```
with(mtcars, table(cyl,gear))
```

Comment: I think there's value in keeping a uniform style in a script. Also if you're trying to get tidyeval to work, it's best to start with small functions. For these reasons it makes sense to answer the original question.

Comment: Part of my problem was lack of clarity in the original question.